# QT: Error trying to store QString in std::pair

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I'm trying to store a QString and a bool in a vector as a pair.
I keep getting the error

> no matching function for call to 'make_pair(bool, QString&)'
>        messages.push_back(make_pair(true, message));

when I run following function:

```
void Class::setMessage(){
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    QString message = time.toString() + "-" + "My message";
    vector<pair<bool,QString>> messages;
    messages.push_back(make_pair<bool,QString>(true, message));
}
```

Whats missing in my code?

Comment: You realize that `messages` will only exist for the scope of this function, right?

Comment: yes of course. just put it like this for the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You don't need to specify the template parameters. They're deduced. I'm assuming you're using std. Perhaps qualify make_pair with std. Remember to include utility.

Also, make sure that the names used are declared the expected scope.

Comment: you are right about specifying the template again. That was the problem. Thanks for the help!